# Convert TimeScript to Date in Azure CosmosDB SQL Query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I select the timescripts of my documents  in Date readable format? I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(C._ts AS DATE) FROM C
```

Specific to Cosmos DB SQL Query  only please.

Answer (score 12):

[Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-timestamptodatetime) announced in October 2020 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-date-and-time-system-functions/ can assist with this (taking care to convert seconds to milliseconds)

```
SELECT TimestampToDateTime(C._ts*1000) as DateTime FROM C
```

Answer (score 6):

Please use [UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) in Cosmos DB.

***sample document:***

[image]

***udf:***

```
function convertTime(unix_timestamp){

      var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var month = ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2);
      var day = ("0"+date.getDate()).substr(-2);
      var hour = ("0"+date.getHours()).substr(-2);
      var minutes = ("0"+date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
      var seconds = ("0"+date.getSeconds()).substr(-2);

      return year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
}
```

SQL: `SELECT udf.convertTime(c._ts) FROM c`

[image]

Surely , you could refer to varied format in this case: [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Nice thanks, +1  is there a benefit to use the engine to convert or  best will be to use JavaScript client side? I will go for client side...

Comment: Need to pass the timestamp into the date call

var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);

Comment: SELECT udf.convertTime(c.CommandDatetimeEpoch) as CommandDate FROM  c where c.DeviceId='asc' 
and c.CommandDate = '09/21/2019'... Can you suggest why this doesnt work?