# Cosmos DB Udf not working with Where condition

Tags: javascript, c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

By referring this i have created a udf to apply date filter ,

[Convert TimeScript to Date in Azure CosmosDB SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158369/convert-timescript-to-date-in-azure-cosmosdb-sql-query).

SELECT udf.convertTime(c.DatetimeEpoch) as CommandDate FROM  c where c.columnH='acb' 
and c.CommandDate = '09/21/2019',

But this query doesnot work when i gave the udf out put in where clause.

Comment: It wont, because your "where" clause is based on data in the table, not the subset of data selected by your query. You would need to use something like a subquery, or a cte, or a temp table or a table variable to hold the results, and then query those separately.

Comment: After adding UDF to where clause it worked fine. As i am new to cosmos db not sure about the performnace. Which is the best practice out of 1) Use C# logic for filtering 2) UDF as i have written alreasy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CosmosDb, you can't use the alias CommandDate in the where clause, unlike in MSSQL. You have to repeat the udf again in the where clause as @Tony Ju answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Unicorno Marley has explained clearly why your sql didn't work.

You can modify your sql as below:

```
SELECT udf.convertTime(c.DatetimeEpoch) as CommandDate FROM c where c.columnH='acb' and udf.convertTime(c.DatetimeEpoch) = '09/21/2019'
```

**EDIT:** You can now use sub-query to avoid repeat execution of UDFs

```
SELECT s.CommandDate 
FROM (
    SELECT udf.convertTime(c.DatetimeEpoch) AS CommandDate 
    FROM c 
    where c.columnH = 'acb'
) s
WHERE s.CommandDate = '09/21/2019'
```

Ideally though you should perform this mapping client side instead of server-side UDFs, because UDF filters in the WHERE clause would be scans.

Comment: @Unicorno Marley Which is the best option UDF or filtering through C# code?

Comment: @jubi No documentation indicates that this will affect performance. Here is an document about performance tips for .net sdk. Hope it helps.